# If $y = \sin^{-1} x$, show that, $(1 - x^2) y_5 - 7xy_4 - 9y_3 = 0$

Tags: calculus

I tried differentiating it consecutively till $y_3$, but the answer gets really big and too complicated to solve.

$y_3 = \frac{(1- x^2 -3x)}{(1-x^2)}^{5/2}$ is the answer I get.

Edit 1: y is the equation. $y_1$ is the first derivative. $y_2$ is the second... and so on

Comment: Assuming $y_k=\frac{d^ky}{dx^k}$. Start with $\sin y=x$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec y$.

Comment: Perhaps you can start with $(1-x^{2})y_1=1$ and keep differentiating both side till you get $y_5$. Not very sure if this is simple but worth a try.

Comment: Wait, do you mean assume x as sin y i.e. x= sin y because there is no $sin {y}$ in the equation.

Comment: He just used properties of inverses. You need to explain your notation. Do you mean derivatives?

Comment: Yeah, it's derivatives. Didn't know that notation wasn't that popular around the world.

y is the equation. $y_1$ is the first derivative. $y_2$ is the second... and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint;

$$y_1=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$\implies y_1^2(1-x^2)=1$$

Differentiate both sides $$y_1^2(-2x)+2y_1y_2(1-x^2)=0$$

As $y_1\ne0,$ $$y_1(-x)+y_2(1-x^2)=0$$

Apply [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule),

$$(fg)^3=\sum_{r=0}^3\binom3rf^{3-r}g^r$$

Answer (score 2):

$y = \sin^{-1} x\implies y_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\qquad \text{where} \quad y_1\equiv \frac{dy}{dx}$

Squaring both side,

$y_1^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies (1-x^2)y_1^2=1$

Differentiating we get

$2(1-x^2)y_1y_2-2xy_1^2=0$

$\implies (1-x^2)y_2-xy_1=0\qquad$

Differentiating $n$ time by Leibnitz's theorem, we get

$(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-2nxy_{n+1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}y_n(-2)-xy_{n+1}-ny_n=0$

$\implies (1-x^2)y_{n+2} -(2n+1)xy_{n+1}-n^2y_n=0$

Now for your case $n=3$

So we get, $$ (1-x^2)y_{5} -7xy_{4}-9y_3=0$$

---

> **Leibnitz's Formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of a product:**
>
> If $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$, each possessing derivatives upto $n^{th}$h order, then the $n^{th}$ derivative of their product is given by
>
> $$(uv)_n=u_nv+^nC_1 u_{n-1}v_1+^nC_2u_{n-2}v_2+\quad. . . \quad+^nC_ru_{n-r}v_r+\quad. . . \quad+ uv_n$$